# Trigger not firing in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem with a trigger in MySQL.

My table is the following :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Possessioncartes (
id_carte SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (id_carte, pseudonyme),
CONSTRAINT fk_inv_carte_id_possession FOREIGN KEY (id_carte) REFERENCES Cartes(id_carte) on delete cascade on update cascade,
pseudonyme VARCHAR(40),
CONSTRAINT fk_inv_carte_pseudo_possession FOREIGN KEY (pseudonyme) REFERENCES Joueurs(pseudonyme) on delete cascade on update cascade,
date_possession DATETIME NOT NULL,
methode_possession VARCHAR(20),
date_non_possession DATETIME,
etat SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
);
```

and my trigger :

```
create trigger posseder after insert on Possessioncartes
for each row begin
set @date_non_possession = new.date_possession
where @id_carte = new.id_carte;
end$$
```

( When I add a new card to the table, the trigger should update all the rows that has the same ID )

when I tried to add a new row, I got no errors but no row was updated.

I tried omitting the @ but I got an "unknown system variable" error.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your trigger does not really make much sense. `@` variables are _session_ variables that are effectively global, and restricted to, the connection they are assigned on. There is no `SET...WHERE` syntax. What are you trying to accomplish with the trigger?

Comment: Is there a way to trigger a changement on rows already in the table ?

Comment: _"the trigger should update all the rows that has the same ID"_... oh, you can't do that. Triggers cannot modify the table they are "ON" outside of the row that triggered them (via `NEW`). in fact, they cannot modify the data in any table involved in the query that triggered them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers cannot modify the table they are "ON", nor any table involved in the query that triggered them.

For example an update trigger on A, cannot modify B for an update statement like `UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON something SET A.x = somethingelse....`